# How to add Locale to DecimalFormatter in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying this code I want apply Locale.US to below code How to do this?

```
public String removeDecimalFormat(Double valueDouble) {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
    format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
    format.setGroupingUsed(true);
    return format.format(valueDouble);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Answer (score 0):

DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats decimal numbers. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

You can try this,it will work :

```
public String removeDecimalFormat(Double valueDouble) {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);//here you can add the locale
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
        format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
        format.setGroupingUsed(true);
        return format.format(valueDouble);
      }
```

Comment: is this downcasting will work?? DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;

Comment: Yeah absolutely, please refer the link mentioned.